# Get all objects where related object has non-blank field in Django ORM?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I've got two models:

```
Company:
  pk
  ...
Supplier:
  pk
  mobile_phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='', blank=True, verbose_name="Мобильный телефон")
  company_id
  ...
```

So:

- Company may have *many* Suppliers
- Supplier may belong to *one* Company

**How to get all Companies, which have at least one Supplier with non-blank mobile_phone?**

Tried:

1. `return queryset.filter(suppliers__mobile_phone__iregex=r’^(?!\s*$).+’)` Returns queryset with duplicates
2. `return queryset.exclude(suppliers__isnull=True).exclude(suppliers__mobile_phone__exact=‘’)` Doesn't work when Company has 2 suppliers, which of them doen't have `mobile_phone`.

Any help // link to docs is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If option 1 is working for you minus the fact that it's returning duplicates you can use distinct() on a field like the documentation says: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/

Answer (score 1):

If your `mobile_phone` could be empty, don't use `default=''`, use `null=True`. Then you might be able to try:

```
Company.objects.filter(supplier__mobile_phone__isnull=False)
```

Comment: DB was already schemed and I can't apply any transformations. So, thought your answer is technically correct, I have to accept `.distinct()` solution by @Michael Platt. But, once again for newcomers: this is actually the correct one for a fresh DB. +1, sir, thank you 8)